# too dumb for auto timestamp in mariadb

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I constantly fail while trying to add a auto timestamp field. Whenever I insert new test data I get an Error message as shown in the image. However I set the type to timestamp and the default to current timestamp. What am I missing?

[image: The Error message]
[image: my structure]

Comment: Please add the full query as text in the question

Comment: If the default value is `current_timestamp()` is shouldn't have `.000000` at the end of it.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin and MariaDB versions are you using, please?